# Getting rid of session and socket pooling sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, express, sails.js

Hi I am current working on my rest api app using sails. I was reading the following article 
http://engineering.linkedin.com/nodejs/blazing-fast-nodejs-10-performance-tips-linkedin-mobile

In point 2 it was suggested to get rid of socket pooling

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {.....};
options.agent = false;
var req = http.request(options)
```

and in point 7 it suggest to get rid of session by removing.

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat" }));
```

I am wondering how I can do that in sails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sails.js v0.10 you can disable the session by adding the following key to your `config/express.js` file:

```
middleware: {
   session: null
}
```

As far as socket pooling goes, I think they're talking about making http requests *from* the server, and just suggesting that when making such requests, you set the `agent` option to `false`.

Comment: sadly not working for me. Anything to be aware of except setting this?

Comment: I have my sessions stored in redis (configuration in session.js) but I'd like to deactivate storing sessions fully. So I thought when I include your code into express.js there shouldn't be any further entries in my redis instance. Right? When I remove the redis configuration from session.js its fine but I fear that the sessions will be stored somewhere in memory after that. Which would be bad. Can I check that somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

For Sails v0.11x, you should use the recommended approach of editing .sailsrc file, and setting:

```
{
   "hooks": {
        "session": false,
        // also useful when building an API
        "grunt": false,
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't work for me. It's asking me to set up the session secret instead.

Comment: @Yun - See bottom of http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-session :  Note: If the session hook is disabled, the session secret configured as sails.config.session.secret will still be used to support signed cookies, if relevant. If the session hook is disabled AND no session secret configuration exists for your app (e.g. because you deleted config/session.js), then signed cookies will not be usable in your application. To make more advanced changes to this behavior, you can customize any of your app's HTTP middleware manually using sails.config.http.